# date_select pass date so that ruby can read it

Tags: ruby, forms, datetime

I have this date_select:

```
date_select("start_date_variable", 
            "start_date_attribute", 
            :start_year => 2014, 
            :end_year => 2016, 
            :order => [:day, :month, :year], 
            :use_short_month => true, 
            :add_month_numbers => true)
```

that returns the date in params as:

```
"start_date_variable" => {
                          "start_date_attribute(3i)"=>"14",
                          "start_date_attribute(2i)"=>"8", 
                          "start_date_attribute(1i)"=>"2016"
                         }
```

I can get the day, month and year from that but I then want to search the database with something like:

```
@orders_from = @fulfillable_orders.where('created_at >= :start_date_par,
                                         :start_date_par => params[:start_date_variable])
```

However I am not sure how to pass the date in a format that ruby will recognize, read and return the records.

Any clue how this is possible or a different way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this gem [multiparameter_attributes_handler](https://github.com/reggieb/multiparameter_attributes_handler).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date_hash = {
  "start_date_attribute(3i)"=>"14", 
  "start_date_attribute(2i)"=>"8", 
  "start_date_attribute(1i)"=>"2016"
}

# will be: '2016-8-14'
date_string = date_hash.values.join('-').reverse

Date.parse(date_string)
```

**EDIT:**

For a stricter validation of the date-format you could use Date#strptime:

```
Date.strptime(date_string', '%Y-%m-%d')
```